# JFileChooser не видит подключенный телефон. Возможно ли вообще его увидеть?

Tags: java, swing

Можно ли в JFileChooser увидеть подключенный к компьютеру телефон? На данный момент JFileChooser все, кроме телефона.
[image: Так выглядит окно JFileChooser]

[image: Так выглядит окно File Explorer]